# Google Maps API Blocked for certain server

Tags: google-maps, static, blocking

Google Maps API static maps is blocking my website's maps..  The site is on a load balancer, so the map is only blocked on one of the servers and seems to be only blocked when viewing the map that was sent in an Email.  The users see a red X with a thottle image representing overused.

If I view the map in a browser using the Javascript V3 version of the same map on the same device, it is fine.  Or if I end up on another server (load balancer), then it is fine.  It is just a specific server viewing an email with the map in the email.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap? (example - doesn't work outside of the code)

My question is to try and understand what is happening.  When viewing an email with the Static map, it is the end user (receiver of the email) that is downloading the Map.  There is no way any of them reached a 2,500 view limit in a day.  All the emails come from one server, but when viewing I do not think this is a factor since it is only when I am on a specific web server that I get the problem.

Can anyone explain what is happening?

BTW, I have contacted Google Business Premier group and have not received a response yet.  I need a work-around while I figure out what and if they want to charge me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make sure that you're not embedding the image itself in the email, but instead are including an  tag that loads the map directly from Google.  If your email blasting program is downloading the image and embedding it in the email you could easily go over that limit based on how many images and emails you send.

It would be worth looking at the HTML source of the email and making sure that you're loading the map directly from Google.  If you are, any over quota problems you've run into might be limited to your current IP address.  Checking the email from a different IP (simulating one of your end users) should be a much better test.

Comment: Thank you.  Good advice.  The google map is in and IMG tag <imrg src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?...">  So i think that is correct.  The current IP that is not working that I can test is through my iPhone or iPad...so it would be one from AT&T.  When I am on their 3G / 4G networks.

Comment: Based on your comments, I did some further testing to isolate the problem.  1) doesn't matter which server my device is on.  2)  Only happens (for this test) on my iPhones, when reading the email with the map.  2) IP's are from AT&T, very similar on 2 phones, but different (145, 147).  iPad reading email on 3G works today, but has had trouble (.18 IP)  3) Only happens when reading the email.  I posted the same HTML on a web page and viewed on the same device and it works.   Making any sense?  Maybe they blocked a range of IP's?   However, not sure that makes sense since it works in a browser.

Comment: one more piece of evidence...My iPad was on Ip .18 and working even on the email map.  I waited a while and checked again...it changed to .20.  Now it is blocked.  I wonder if they blocked a whole range of IP's ...?  Not sure how to fix that...

Comment: Carriers commonly share IP addresses between devices and users.  There's a good chance other users are using the same IP and have used up some of the static maps quota.